# Reverse for 'profile' with arguments '(None,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)\\Z']

Tags: django

I'm getting the above error and I've tweaked my code based on answers I saw online but still getting the same error

VIEWS.PY
`

```
def profile(request, user_id):
    profile_user = User.objects.get(pk = user_id)
    # user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user_object)
    profile_post = NewTweet.objects.filter(user = user_id)
    post_count = len(profile_post)
    follower = request.user.id
    user = user_id

    if Followers.objects.filter(follower=follower, user=user).first():
        button_text = "Unfollow"
    else:
        button_text = "Follow"

    context = {
        "profile_user": profile_user,
        "post_count": post_count,
        "profile_post": profile_post,
        "button_text": button_text,
    }
    return render(request, "network/profile.html", context)
```

`

URL.PY

```
    path("profile/<int:user_id>", views.profile, name="profile"),
```

LAYOUT.HTML
`

```
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'profile' user.id %}">
                                        <img src= {% static 'network/images/profile.svg' %} alt="Profile" class="left-sidebar-menu-icon">
                                        Profile
                                    </a>
                                    
                                    <img src= {% static 'network/images/profile.svg' %} alt="Profile" class="left-sidebar-menu-icon">
                                        Profile
                                </li>
```

`

MODELS.PY

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id_user = models.IntegerField()
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Followers(models.Model):
    follower = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # follower = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='targets')
    # target = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='followers')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

In Layout.html, I try '{{ user.id }}' to see what is reflecting and it shows 'None'. Please advise

In Layout.html, I try '{{ user.id }}' to see what is reflecting and it shows 'None'.

I also adjusted this as adviced in a different thread but same error message

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'profile' user_id=user.id %}">
```

I expect that it would show me a button text of 'Follow' or 'Unfollow depending on if the user is currently following the current user

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

There is no `user` in the context you create in the view: `user.id` is None because there isn't a variable called `user`. Since you already have `user_id` in the view, you only need to add it in the context and, in the template, use `user_id` instead of `user.id`.

Comment: I made the following edit

    context = {
        "profile_user": profile_user,
        "button_text": button_text,
        "user_id": user_id,
    }

LAYOUT.HTML

                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'profile' user_id %}">
                                    </a>

ERROR - Reverse for 'profile' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)\\Z']

Comment: From the error message it seems that user_id is an empty string. What happens if you try to display it with {{ user_id }}?

Comment: It shows 'None'

Comment: What about user_id in the view? What kind of object is it?

Comment: Thank you @StefanoTrv, I've been able to resolve this